# How to validate forms step by step with bootstrap and angular form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I find this example [step-by-step form with bootstrap and angularjs](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrimes/58wqH/)

How can I validate the email before jump to step 2 ??
or block the step jump until the fields are full??

```
function RegisterCtrl($scope, $location) {

  $scope.steps = [
    'Step 1: Team Info',
    'Step 2: Campaign Info',
    'Step 3: Campaign Media'
  ];

....some code
```

Answer (score 1):

First, define your model in your controller:

```
function RegisterCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.step1 = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        passwordc: ''
     };
    //...
```

Bind it to your form fields:

```
<input type="text" id="inputEmail" ng-model="step1.email" placeholder="Email">
```

Next, do your validation inside gotoStep():

```
  $scope.goToStep = function(index) {
        if (!$scope.step1.email.match(/[a-z0-9\-_]+@[a-z0-9\-_]+\.[a-z0-9\-_]{2,}/)) {
              return window.alert('Please specify a valid email');
        }
        //...
```

Obviously alert is not great so use jQuery to `focus()` and add the Bootstrap classes (`control-group warning`) to highlight the field.

http://jsfiddle.net/xayzP/

Answer (score 1):

You should use [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to test your form field vadility, e.g:

```
app.directive('email', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                if (viewValue && viewValue.match(/[a-z0-9\-_]+@[a-z0-9\-_]+\.[a-z0-9\-_]{2,}/)) {
                    // it is valid
                    ctrl.$setValidity('email', true);
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
                    ctrl.$setValidity('email', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In your html, you need to add the directive to your input field. You can show error messages if a field is not valid using the `myForm.email.$error` object:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" email required>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email" class="help-inline">Email invalid</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required" class="help-inline">Email required</span>
```

You can disable the next link until the form is valid by using [myForm.$invalid](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) on [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass):

```
<li ng-class="{disabled: myForm.$invalid}" >
   <a ng-model="next" ng-click="incrementStep(myForm)">Next Step &rarr;</a>
</li>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/YXKMU/).